# color percentage in image python opencv using histogram

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I am beginner in python and image processing. I want to find the percentage of brown color from an image using histogram function.

I did the histogram function but I do not know how to find the percentage of the brown color in the image.

this is my python code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('C:\Users\MainUser\Desktop\histogram\dates.jpg', -1)
cv2.imshow('GoldenGate',img)

color = ('b','g','r')
for channel,col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[channel],None,[256],[0,256])
    plt.plot(histr,color = col)
    plt.xlim([0,256])
plt.title('Histogram for color scale picture')
plt.show()

while True:
    k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF     
    if k == 27: break             # ESC key to exit 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the image that I use

[image: the image that I use]

I have this output of the code
[image]

Comment: Do you want to accomplish this strictly using histogram ?

Comment: Technically I used the histogram approach in my answer by integrating over the color channels and taking the subset of the integrals that are corresponding to the desired color. Nevertheless, I agree with you that the question is open to interpretation in this regard. Guess it's time for the author to respond.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('J9MbW.jpg')

brown = [145, 80, 40]  # RGB
diff = 20
boundaries = [([brown[2]-diff, brown[1]-diff, brown[0]-diff],
               [brown[2]+diff, brown[1]+diff, brown[0]+diff])]
# in order BGR as opencv represents images as numpy arrays in reverse order

for (lower, upper) in boundaries:
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype=np.uint8)
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype=np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

    ratio_brown = cv2.countNonZero(mask)/(img.size/3)
    print('brown pixel percentage:', np.round(ratio_brown*100, 2))

    cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([img, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This should work for you. However, note that it is highly dependent on your RGB value of brown as well as your desired tolerance (`diff`).

If you have further questions on the details of the above code, feel free to ask.

Comment: amazing, thanks very much it works with me. but the percentage is always 0? whatever the picture

Comment: You were correct, that the percentage had an issue - for color images img.size yields apparently the number of pixels times the number of channels - so i added '/3' to the answer and tested the percentage with a test image that was half brown. For the image provided above the code yields me 9.78% 'brown' pixels. Nevertheless, recall that the results still are strongly dependent on your definition of 'brown' and your tolerance (diff). Further, if you would rather check for 'darker' vs 'brighter' regions, maybe set separate tolerances for the lower and upper boundaries.

Comment: unfortunately still appearing 0 percentage :(

Comment: What versions of opencv, numpy and Python do u use?

Comment: python 2.7.3 - numpy 1.8 - opencv 3.1

Comment: i did it with python 3.5, numpy 1.12 and opencv 3.1   - could you check it with these versions?

Comment: Actually I need it in version 2.7.3 could you please help me sir? please

Answer (score 0):

I was in need of the same results, so I used your code and made it calculate percentages.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import operator

img = cv2.imread('azul200.png', -1)
cv2.imshow('Imagem:',img)

color = ('b','g','r')
qtdBlue = 0
qtdGreen = 0
qtdRed = 0
totalPixels = 0

for channel,col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[channel],None,[256],[1,256])
    plt.plot(histr,color = col)
    plt.xlim([0,256])
    totalPixels+=sum(histr)
    print histr
    if channel==0:
        qtdBlue = sum(histr)
    elif channel==1:
        qtdGreen = sum(histr)
    elif channel==2:
        qtdRed = sum(histr)

qtdBlue = (qtdBlue/totalPixels)*100
qtdGreen = (qtdGreen/totalPixels)*100
qtdRed = (qtdRed/totalPixels)*100

qtdBlue = filter(operator.isNumberType, qtdBlue)
qtdGreen = filter(operator.isNumberType, qtdGreen)
qtdRed = filter(operator.isNumberType, qtdRed)

plt.title("Red: "+str(qtdRed)+"%; Green: "+str(qtdGreen)+"%; Blue: "+str(qtdBlue)+"%")
plt.show()
```

I hope it helps, worked great for me.